# how to use callback function between parent and child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

my problem is I want to handle the active link (`<a class="active" >`) between components.

## Introduce :

when you select a channel, and at the same time you select a user from the direct message components. In this case, the two links "`<a>`" will be active.

[image: Sidebar]

Parent class :

```js
class SidePanel {
    
    render(){
        
        const {currentUser} = this.props;

        return(
            <Menu>
               // Childs :
               <Channels currentUser={currentUser} />{' '}
               <DirectMessages  currentUser={currentUser} />

            </Menu>
        );
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will execute sending message process in Parent and inject the result of direct messages 
to `DirectMessages` compoennt as below.

In your `Channel` component

```js
...

class channel extens Component {
  handleChannelSelect = (channelId) => {
    if this.props.handleChannelSelect && this.props.handleChannelSelect(channelId);
  }
}

...
```

SidePanel (Parent Component)

```js
   class SidePanel {
     handleChannelSelect = async (channelId) => {
      const messageResult = await serverApi.sendDirectMessage(channelId);
      this.setState({ messageResult });
    }

    return(
      <Menu>
        // Childs :
        <Channels currentUser={currentUser} handleChannelSelect={this.handleChannelSelect}/>{' '}
        <DirectMessages  currentUser={currentUser} messages={this.state.messageResult} />
      </Menu>
    );
  }
```

## Why

It is not fixed way, but I prefer to get together backend process in Top screen component or using flux architecture to control client-server communication. And make component to concentrate how to show the result.

[Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/)

Comment: @Pokemon Good :) Do not forget to check the useful answer.

Comment: Yeah cool, I didn't know before "flux" thanks for the info. but let's return to my question I've tried looking forward the answer but without any kind of fixed. Update (SidePanel) => Parent Components , (Channels) : [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/qv854j74r6). have you any suggestion for fixed this issue .

Comment: please have any suggestion for this issue, I'm waiting for a reply

Comment: @Pokemon It is not easy to understand what you want exactly. Where is the active link? What is the two `a` links? Tell me more specific information about the logic.